# Bootstrap CSS and other CSS/HTML component packages

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, kickstrap

I've just started using Bootstrap for a project /w ASP.NET MVC, loving it! amazing! I'm disappointed that there aren't more components available, in terms of, example layout components you can drop in. (I.E a listing, detail, boxes, typography variants in a box) All sorts of things, to speed up development even more.

Are there any additional plugins that Bootstrap offers, or any other CSS/HTML component libraries available that could help me out?

Comment: Also check out Bootstrap Xtra. I more like their [Nav Bar](http://lightglitch.github.com/bootstrap-xtra/#navigation)

Answer (score 2):

Please try [Kickstrap](http://ajkochanowicz.github.com/Kickstrap/). That is a full version of **Twitter's Bootstrap** with themes, enhancements, and other goodies.

Comment: +1 I've started playing with it today. It's pretty impressive so far, although it feels like I've barely scratched the surface!

Answer (score 0):

The following link points to Bootstrap HTML Helpers.. they don't add much new in terms of components, but they do make the code cleaner and speed up development:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507569/Bootstrap-HTML-Helpers

Hope this helps.